# Почему "печЁнка"?

Tags: орфография

Почему слово "печенка" (например, в выражении "сидеть в печенках") пишется через Ё, в то время, как, например, "девчОнка" - через О?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что в слове *печенка* - буква *ё* находится в корне слова и есть чередование *е/ё* (печёнка - печень). А в слове девчонка (ручонка, речонка) - орфограмма в суффиксе существительного. Здесь работает другое правило: под ударением - О. Т. е., решая вопрос, что писать, Ё или О, надо определить часть речи и морфему.