# Стрижонка/стрижёнка

Tags: орфография

Как правильно писать: *стрижёнка* (я думаю, так) или *стрижонка*, если имеется не птица в виду, а стрижка? Почему именно так? Я думаю, что через *ё*, т. к. это как *почёный — печёнка*, но то, что мне не нравится, — это тот факт, что в *стриженый* ударение не на *е* (хотя я бы без зазрения совести *стрижёные волосы* смог бы таки сказать).

Comment: Печёнка не от слова печёный, а от слова печь.

Comment: _Печонка_ от слова печь, а _печенка_ от _печеный_.

Comment: Precisely! Exactly!

Comment: @Максим от слова печь - печушка. И не печенка, а печенька, от печенье)

Comment: @Буратино    Это у кого как.  Печенка – это ПИРОЖКИ, которые в печонке испекли.  А еще есть печень – печенка, но я ее не люблю.  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4101/Почему-печЁнка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Как  два сленговых слова между собой поспорили**

Встретились  ***стрижонка*** и ***стрижёнка***  и косо поглядывают друг на друга.  Спорят, кто из них неправильно написан.

— Я — существительное, — говорит ***стрижонка***. — У меня суффикс ***ОНК***.

— И я существительное, — возражает ***стрижёнка***. — У меня суффикс ***К.***

— А ***ЁН*** у тебя откуда, на улице нашла?

— В основе у меня ***ЁН***,  я  от прилагательного ***стриженый***.  Сравни: ***тушеный — тушенка***. А ты где корень ***СТРИЖ*** взяла, на улице нашла?  Ты от какого слова образована?

— От ***стричь***!  Там чередование ***Ч/Г/Ж***!

— Да?  От глагола ***стричь***  нельзя образовать существительное, потому что ***ОНК*** — суффикс **субъективной** оценки, он подходит  при образовании от других существительных.

И не знает ***стрижонка***, что ответить.  Вроде бы корень ***СТРИЖ*** и суффикс ***ОНК*** не на улице нашла, а доказать ничего не может.  Плохо не знать, от чего ты образована и как ты образована.

А все дело в том,  что есть ***стрижонка (стрижка)*** как модель, а есть ***стриженка***  — остриженные волосы. Разве нет?

Но ведь это сленг, а **в словаре**  этих слов не найдешь. Поэтому словообразовательные и толковые словари вам в помощь, если вы хотите свое сленговое словечко **правильно** записать.

Comment: Гениально! Именно так!

Answer (score 0):

Мой вариант: ***стрижонка.***

**Пояснение**

Суффикс существительного ***ОНК***, ***О*** в ударной позиции после шипящих.

**Схема** словообразования: ***стричь — стриж/к/а — стриж/онк/а.***

***К*** — суффикс существительного, образует сущ. со значением **результата действия** (*записать — записка, выдумать — выдумка, настоять — настойка*).

Далее усечение основы на ***К*** и суффикс **существительного** ***ОНК***  с уменьшительно-уничижительным или с уменьшительно-ласкательным значением. Фактически это замена нейтрального суффикса ***К*** суффиксом **субъективной оценки.**

**[Толковый словарь Ефремовой](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/250982/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0)**

**СТРИЖКА** ж. 1. действие по гл. стричь, стричься I **2. Прическа, которая получается в результате** подстригания волос. Толковый словарь Ефремовой. Т. Ф. Ефремова.

**ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ.** От глагола ***стричь*** нельзя образовать существительное с помощью суффикса ***ОНК***. Такого значения нет у Ефремовой. Можно образовать сущ. от сущ.

Answer (score 0):

Верно через О:

*Стрижонка*.

В суффиксах существительных после шипящих пишется буква О, если она под ударением; если нет — Е: *книжóнка, избу́шенка*.

А приведенное вами слово, *печëнка*, пишется с Е по другой причине.

Разбор: корень *стриж-*, суффикс *-онк-*, окончание *-а*;

*Печенка*: корень *печен-*, суффикс *-к-*, окончание *-а*.

В слове *стрижонка* ударная буква О в суффиксе, а в слове *печенка* нет суффикса *-енк-*, так что правилу это не подчиняется.

Comment: Можно предположить: стричь — стриженый — стриженка,  как тушить —тушеный — тушенка. Докажите, что это не так. С печенью все ясно, там ЕН в корне.  Надо словообразование рассматривать.

Comment: @Sharon Смортите, в слове _стрижонка_ суффикс -ОНК- сразу видно, что уменьшительно-ласкательный. В слове _тушенка_ видно, что, напротив, здесь совсем не так. Слово _тушенка_ происходит от причастия _тушеный_, в котором суффикс -ЕН-,  который сохраняется и в существительном. То есть способ образования суффиксальный и от причастия, а не другого существительного с тем же корнем, к которому приделали суффикс -ЕНК-. По сути, из причастия взяли основу ТУШЕН-, вместе с суффиксом, и добавили суффикс -К-, сделав существительное.

Comment: В слове _тушенка_ два суффикса. Один от причастия, другой добавили. Если образовывать уменьшительно-ласкательное от существительное, прибавив суффикс -ЕНК-, то от какого? _Туша_, что ли? Нет, это слово от глагола _тушить_.

Comment: Решается вопрос: слово образовано от глагола или от существительного. Поэтому схему приведите. У вас как: стричь - стрижонка. Такой схемы нет, Посмотрите по Тихонову, у него я не нашла. Смотрела у Ефремовой. И вы смотрите и схему приведите. Все по серьезной науке надо, а не по собственным рассуждениям.  А у вас лирика одна. Это же форум лингвистов)

Comment: @Sharon Рассуждения тоже имеют свойства истинности или ложности. Главное, чтоб было доказано и доказательства были верные. Я считаю, что у меня все верно доказано и рассуждения верные. Или я в чëм-то не прав?

Comment: Доказывая, я ориентировался на словообразования этих слов.

Comment: А схема где?  Если от глагола  (глаг. прилагательного) образовано, то Ё надо писать.  А рассуждения имеют один критерий верности: это мое рассуждение, поэтому оно верное.  СЛОАРИ, пожалуйста, вот критерии верности.

Comment: НЕТОЧНЫЙ ОТВЕТ!  Решение верное, а объяснение недоказанное: способ образования слова так не объясняют.  Когда научимся работать КАЧЕСТВЕННО? Никогда?  Тогда мне тоже надоело ходить за вами и исправлять ошибки. Пусть еще кто=нибудь этим займется.

Comment: @Sharon А как тогда способ образования объясняют, чтоб доказанно было? Спрашиваю максимально спокойно сейчас, никакой злости не испытываю.

Comment: Качественно или нет — главное, чтоб доказано было, чтоб итог был, чтоб было понятно и правильно. Из _качественно_ и _понятно_ лучше выбрать второй вариант, он больше сути занимает в ответе. И всë доказано к тому же. Или как нужно доказывать, если не так, как словообращование по-другому объяснять?

Comment: Это не злость, Максим, это сожаление.  Бывало время, когда на форуме был очень ВЫСОКИЙ уровень,  а вот такого НИЗКОГО я не помню.  Есть две исходные формы: стриженый и стричь.  От выбора схемы зависит решение: О в отыменной форме и Ё в отглагольной. Обе схемы нужно рассмотреть. У вас нет ничего похожего.  Откуда у вас корень СТРИЖ? Ниоткуда, сам по себе.  И  это качество?  Вы ведь даже не понимаете, что именно так делается анализ.  Нет желания работать не таком форуме.  А всем как бы и безразлично.

Comment: И вас просто не узнать. Вы же писали, что пришли сюда учиться.  А теперь за пару месяцев выучились всему и во всем разобрались.  И даже слушать ничего не хотите. Сколько времени разбирали вставки!  И вы повторяете те же ошибки, которые делали раньше.

Comment: @Sharon Я что угодно могу выслушать, если мне дать доказательства, которым я поверю. Если бы вы сразу дали ссылку (про вопрос о слове _ограниче..ны_), а не кричали, что ответ неверный, я бы не продолжил спор. По вставкам. Вы, наверное, скажете, что вы по отнесенности вставок дали мне необходимые доказательства. Я с вами не согласился, потому что считаю по-другому. Запятая всегда ставится после скобок, но в ... из тире может перед любым тире. Так что сравнивать со скобками не доказательство. Надо отнесенность вставки смотреть. Ладно, вы сказали, что к первой. Я так не считал, поэтому не согласи

Comment: Да, я, возможно, действительно сильно изменился. Но чем меньше знаешь, тем меньше ты будешь спорить. А сейчас я узнал намного больше, поэтому мнения у меня, как и у любого человека, тоже появились свои. Поэтому спорю с некоторыми утверждениями, потому что знаю правила и опровержения. Каждому человеку свойственны свои мнения, — такова природа.

Comment: Вы про первую запятую у Грамоты спрашивали.  Вам сказали, что нужна. И вот вы в такой же ситуации ее не ставите. Почему? Потому что ничего не поняли из своего же вопроса-ответа и правильного вывода не сделали.  Ладно, я вас больше "воспитывать" не буду. У вас высокая репутация... Очень часто Лео принимает вши ответы, да?   А другие часто принимают?

Answer (score -1):

Стрижка не имеет внутреннего наполнения или содержания, стрижка полностью зависит от внешнего восприятия. Поэтому суффикс онок/ёнок(обладающий чем-то), так же как и суффикс онк/ёнк(состоящий из), - не могут быть употреблены.

Например: самогонка - сделанная из самогона, по средствам перегонки. Стрижка не состоит из состриженных волос, наоборот, она то, что осталось после стрижки. То есть цель стрижки и результат совершенно противоположны.

Хотя самогонка не самый удачный пример)

ладно, отдельно ёнк - по всей видимости может быть суффиксом образующим слова вроде от глаголов, однако эти глаголы сами образованы от форм женского рода, либо глаголов без ёнк и др суффиксов.

Сгущёнка-сгущать-гуща. Корень гущ, можно образовать гущёнка.

> Седьмая вода на гуще (на гущенке)
> Перм. Ирон. То же, что девятая вода на киселе. Сл. Акчим. 1, 138.

Обнажёнка-обнажать-нагая.

А стрижка - как образовать слово без -ка? Стрига, стрижа?

> | Стрига, стриженая щетина, с живой свиньи, самая плохая. Даль

Как видно, подтверждается первое предположение, что стрига - это указание на отрезанные волосы, а не на стрижку свиньи после.

> | Стриган, яросл. стригун (общее), стригунок, стригунчик, стригунец, стрижек пермяц. перегодовалый жеребенок, у которого об эту пору остригают гриву. В старину езжали на стригуну, на двулетке.
> | Стригун муж. -гунья жен., новг. и стригуша ·об. стригач муж. кто стрижет других, парикмахер, шутл. волосопут. И призва (Далила) стригача, и остриже седм пленице влас главы его (Сампсона), Суд.

Волосопут - парикмахер, следовательно волосопутка - стрижка, может быть. Ну может быть тут волосопутёнка, но опять же как следствие и цель действия, а не как побочный продукт стрижки.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150017/discussion-on-answer-by---); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.